# Multi forms on one page using ajax handler not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have two ajax forms on one page, the first one is set to hide after it has been submitted and this works perfectly, my problem is when I submit the second one with the presence of the 1st one it wouldn`t work (when I click the submit nothing happens) although it works when I submit it after the first when has been hidden..

here are my two forms codes and the ajax handler

```
    <!-- Form 1 -->
    <div class="panel-heading " role="tab">
    <input type="submit" class="deep_blue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post_form" value="Add Origin Text">
    <div class="modal fade" id="post_form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="postModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
              </span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="postModalLabel">
              <p style="color: #580024; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <b>Add Origin Text
                </b>
              </p>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
               <form action="" method="post" class="profile_post registration-form">
                               <fieldset>
                      <div class="form-bottom">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <p style="color: #580024;">Poet</p>
                        <textarea  class="form-control  btn-" name="addorigin_epoet"><?php echo $epoet_name ?></textarea><br>
                        <p style="color: #580024;">Poem</p>
                        <textarea  class="form-control  btn-"  name="addorigin_epoem"><?php echo $epoem_title ?></textarea><br>
                         <p style="color: #580024;">Origin Title</p>
                        <textarea  class="form-control  btn-" placeholder="..." name="addorigin_otitle"></textarea><br>

                        <p style="color: #580024;">Origin Body</p>
                        <textarea  class="form-control  btn-" placeholder="..." name="addorigin_origin"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_from" value="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="addorigin_ie" value="<?php echo $ie; ?>">

                      </fieldset>

                </form>

                     </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="post_button" id="submit_profile_post"><p">Add</p>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form 2 -->
    <div class="panel-heading " role="tab" id="headingError" >
    <input type="submit" class="deep_blue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post_form2" value="Submit Error">
    <div class="modal fade" id="post_form2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="postModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal2" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
              </span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="postModalLabel2">
              <p style="color: #580024; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <b>Submit Error
                </b>
              </p>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
               <form id="error" action="" method="post" class="profile_post registration-form">
                               <fieldset>
                      <div class="form-bottom">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <p style="color: #580024;">Poet</p>
                        <textarea  class="form-control  btn-" name="error1"><?php echo $epoet_name ?></textarea><br>
                        <p style="color: #580024;">Poem</p>
                        <textarea  class="form-control  btn-"  name="error2"><?php echo $epoem_title ?></textarea><br>
                        <p style="color: #580024;">Error</p>
                        <textarea  class="form-control  btn-" placeholder="Error" name="error3"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_from" value="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>">



          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="post_button" id="submit_profile_post"><p style="color: #580024; margin-bottom: 0px;">Submit</p>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
          </button>      </fieldset>
                </form>

                     </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>



    <!-- ajax_submit_profile_post -->
    if(isset($_POST['addorigin_origin'])) {
      $post = new Post($con, $_POST['user_from']);
      $post->submitPostAddorigin($_POST['addorigin_ie'],$_POST['addorigin_epoet'],$_POST['addorigin_epoem'],$_POST['addorigin_otitle'],$_POST['addorigin_origin']);
    }


    if(isset($_POST['error3'])) {
      $error = new Post($con, $_POST['user_from']);
      $error->submitPostError($_POST['error1'],$_POST['error2'],$_POST['error3']);
    }


$(document).ready(function() {





$('.button_holder').on('click', function() {
    document.search_form.submit();
})

//Button for profile post
$('#submit_profile_post').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/handlers/ajax_submit_profile_post.php",
        data: $('form.profile_post').serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#post_form").modal('hide');
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Failure');
        }
    });

});


});
```

Comment: where is the Ajax code?

Comment: last thing in the above code

Comment: That's PHP code, I guess @shihab was refering to the Javascript part - which is missing

Comment: Can't find ajax code dear. show that one.

Comment: sorry, I added it above

Comment: I think you need to have 2 different ids for each form. `submit_profile_post1` and `submit_profile_post2`

Comment: And you have to send another ajax request for `submit_profile_post2`

Comment: @AkhtarMunir you are right, it worked, thank you very much

Comment: @hasanhasan You welcome dear. kindly make my answer useful for others to get help.